# How do I improve my flask application handling multiple requests?

Tags: python, flask

I'm pretty new to asking questions on stack overflow and building a web app with flask so I apologize in advance if I say something that's incorrect.

I'm building a flask web app that handles scheduling appointments and naturally i'm using 3rd party libraries/wrappers to make API calls and to handle db queries (sqlite). As it is currently, my app doesn't use any kind of async code. I got thinking about scenarios where multiple users try to login or book an appointment, both involving db queries and api calls, and whether my application will block or not. Given that its all synchronous, if multiple users do try and login and book an appointment, will it block for some users while it handles other user requests, or is that all independent of my flask app and dependent on the WSGI server running the app? Any tips on how I can improve the performance of my app with regards to handling multiple requests?

Example route that multiple users try to visit at the same time:

```
...

@app.route('/signup/')
def signup():
    # has a form that takes user input and submits it for processing in process_signup()
    return render_template('signup.html')


@app.route('/process_signup/', methods=['POST'])
def process_signup():
    form = request.forms
    username = form['username']
    password = form['password']

    # insert values into customer db in a synchronous fashion 
    db = db() #gets the database
    cursor = db.execute('insert into customers (username, password) values (?,?)', [username, password])
    db.commit()

    #send out a verification email using email api without any async
    email_new_customer()

    return redirect(url_for('signin'))
```

**NOTE: I read that its better to have db queries and api calls handled asynchronously but not sure where to start or what kind of library compatible with flask will help me achieve that**.

Thank you for your help and again I may have a big misunderstanding of how it all works as i'm very to new to this so I apologize.

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow you present your *non-working* code and get help making it work. Your question is very far from that.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you, I added some example code for context :)

Comment: Have you checked if Flask doesnt already allow that? You could make a route that just sleeps for 30 and send other requests during that time and see how the server reacts. Check threaded = True in the app.run() command

Comment: threaded=True is enabled by default in the flask version i'm using. As it turns out from what I understand now is that there's no changing the fact that flask can only handle one request/response cycle at a time. What can be done though is configure the server with multiple workers to handle more requests. Flask async from its 2.0 version doesn't seem to be much help either as it currently is :/ @c8999c3f964f64

Comment: Yeah thats about what I meant. Flask itself can't handle multiple requests at once, but there's strategies that achieve the same effect as if it could (like multiple workers, threads, instances, load balancing, containers... etc...). Unfortunately, flask's compatibility with other projects would break if they made it natively asynchronous - if I understand that correctly - so its unlikely they're gonna change that in a future version.